# Convert results after CrawlerProcess ends

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I just finish a project with scrapy.
My client wants results as **xlsx** and, cause I didn't find a way to export results like that, I'm exporting to **csv** and then converting xlxs (If this code can be improved, let me know :)

**My problem is** when python execute `csv_2_xlsx(FILE_NAME)` result file does not exist yet. I tried adding a sleep but din't work.

Any help will be welcome :)

My main file is like that:

```
# main.py
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from spiders import my_spider
from exporter import csv_2_xlsx

FILE_NAME = 'result.csv'

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
    'FEED_URI': FILE_NAME,
    'FEED_EXPORTERS' : {
        'csv': 'exporter.FixLineCsvItemExporter',
    }
})

process.crawl(my_spider.MySpider)

# I think python should stop until
# this process ends
process.start()

# this line is not working cause
# result.csv doest not exist yet
csv_2_xlsx(FILE_NAME)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited Version**

I rearranged your code to the following manner in order to solve the csv file not being closed issue.

main.py

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

process.crawl('spider_name')
process.start()
```

Pipeline.py

```
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter
from exporter import csv_2_xlsx


FILE_NAME = 'result.csv'
class TutorialPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.file = open(FILE_NAME, 'wb')
        self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(self.file)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        self.file.close()
        csv_2_xlsx(FILE_NAME)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```

---

Have you tried to add `csv_2_xlsx(FILE_NAME)` into the `pipeline.py` file? In the class definition of the `pipeline.py` file, add a [`close_spider()`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) function and put `csv_2_xlsx(FILE_NAME)` into the function.

```
def close_spider(self, spider):
    csv_2_xlsx(FILE_NAME)
```

Comment: I just checked and didn't work. It looks like exporting process happens after spider closes.

Comment: @Freddy wasn't the `result.csv` generated by the time when the spider terminated?

Comment: did you remember activating the pipeline in `settings.py` ?

Comment: Pipeline is working.
I recorded the problem for better undestanding.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yV9dPMxtmx8

Comment: @Freddy,  I tested and added a new edited version of my code above. Hope it could help you. Please inform me if it still didn't work though.